# Redirection of jupyterlab terminal stdout to system stdout (where jupyter lab is running)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'd like to redirect the stdout of some commands inside a terminal in jupyterlab to the container where is running the jupyterlab for visualization/audit possibilities due to our solution that already logs whatever is being shown to container logs.

How can I get that?

I've seen this post and it seems to work while you're inside of ipykernel: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-no-longer-allows-ouput-to-be-redirected-to-stdout/11535

However, when trying to do the same inside a terminal, appears that the stdout's are different, probably due to some change into the FDs.

I can't figure out the change that i need to redirect to the "system stdout".

How to emulate?

> jupyter lab
> -- Here you're going to have the logs inside of jupyterlab using a log level 30. (tried a lot of logging levels, still can't access the information that i need)

Go inside jupyter lab terminal, do some echo command, and try to make it go back all the way to the terminal that jupyter lab is running.